# Firefox ignores "video/quicktime" MIME Type for file input

Tags: file, firefox, input, mime-types

I have a form with a file input to handle file uploads for images or videos. I want to restrict the accepted file-types to *.jpg*, *.gif*, *.png*, *.mp4* and *.mov*, so I'm using the `accept` option on my `input type="file"` as follows:

```
<input name="message[file]" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif,video/mp4,video/quicktime" type="file">
```

This works basically fine, but Firefox seems to ignore the `video/quicktime` MIME type and the file dialog box shows the *.mov* files as unavailable. All the other accepted file types are available.

I can select the .mov files when I use `video/*` as accepted file-types, but I want to restrict the video-uploads to *.mp4* and *.mov*. According to my research `video/quicktime` is the correct MIME type for .mov files and the WebKit-Browsers work well with it. Why would Firefox not accept the .mov files?

Answer (score 4):

Only MP4, WebM, and Ogg video are supported by the HTML5 standard. Starting from Firefox 45, video/quicktime content type is treated as MP4 media to be handled by the built-in HTML5 video player. But MOV files can contain a variety of different encodings, they are not all MP4.

Comment: I'm using ffmpeg to encode the uploaded videos on the server-side in H.264 _.mp4_ files. Thus they will be _.mp4_ in the end. But iPhone videos for example are .mov files and should be accepted aswell. How would I handle this then without accepting _.avi_ for example?